# What is the source of this Batman artwork that my family member copied?

Tags: dc, batman, episode-identification

The image below is a semi-exact reproduction of a picture found in a Batman issue. It was drawn by a family member and should be reasonably accurate, including the folds of clothing, musculature and shading.

I'm almost certain it was a Gotham Comics (Singapore/India publisher https://www.flickr.com/photos/100723368@N03/albums/72157635691487734) Batman issue (or possibly a Detective Comics issue).

I also clearly remember a panel of Bruce Wayne coming down the wide balustraded central staircase of Wayne Manor in the same issue.

[image]

Comment: Where did you find this image, and are you sure it's from an actual DC comic? Looks like fan art to me.

Comment: It's a very common pose for Batman; http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-KGsMd6oW4NA/Vfqr8rtehvI/AAAAAAAAE1I/KSqzG2bpuzQ/s640/batman_magazine_11.jpg - https://www.puzzle-puzzle.cz/ImgZbozi/Detail/puzzle-batman-batmobile-3d-300-dilku-122160.jpg + https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/91fkzrhJrsL._SY450_.jpg (for example). I think you'll need to be much clearer

Comment: I used to have the comic... this is a drawing from it. The angle and general proportions have to match. @valorum the megazine looks similar but that's not it. The other one, the art style is different.

Comment: So this actual drawing was actually in it? It's not fan-art?

Comment: This was drawn by a family member of mine... but a drawing with the exact same framing, pose, shading, details (like the muscles, wrinkles in the cloak) and color is present in an actual batman comic issue. So while it's technically drawn by a fan, its not fan art in the sense you mean

Comment: @Estin how do you know that, but can't ask what the source is?

Comment: Had the comic, lost the comic, been ~20 yrs, imperfect memory. Was there when the image was drawn

Comment: Hmm. It's not proving easy to lay my hands on these Gotham Comics editions. They seem quite rare and specialised

Answer (score -1):

Not 100%, but this is probably the issue. The cover seems familiar https://www.flickr.com/photos/100723368@N03/16742886171/in/album-72157635691487734/.

Problem is I dont know which standard issue(s) it corresponds to.

Comment: The first spectacular one!